# Quadratic equation roots values was positive but shown as negative

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image]

Hi,

This screen capture was taken from KhanAcademy. I am an adult learner trying to revisit Algebra I/II concepts.

In the video, p was calculated as 1/4 or 4. But, why was is factorized as (p-1/4)(p-4)>0.

Showing -1/4 and -4?

Comment: if $a$ and $b$ are the roots of an equation then the equation can be written as $(x-a)(x-b)=0$, if you expand $(x-1/4)(x-4)$ you will get the original equation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A helpful way to view this problem is "For which values of p is the statement (p-1/4)(p-4)>0 true"?

Since we are dealing with an inequality, there are three possible ranges of values of p we are interested in. The significance of 1/4 and -4 are that they are "division points" of these ranges.

If p < 1/4. Then (p-1/4) is negative and (p-4) is negative. So the product of these two negative numbers is positive.

If 1/4 < p < 4, then the two arguments evaluate to a positive and a negative, respectively. Hence their product is negative. So the equality does not hold true.

If p > 4, both arguments are positive so the result is positive.

Thus, this equality holds true if p is less than 1/4 or greater than 4.

(Note: for p=1/4 or p=4, the statement does not hold true because we are working with a strict inequality.)

Comment: Nice explanation.  However, you meant the significance of $1/4$ and $\color{red}{4}$.